# Can't lock onto GPS. Flash/Root possibly related

Tags: gps, samsung-infuse-4g

I'm really hoping somebody can help me out here because this is frustrating me. First off, I have a Samsung Infuse 4G with AT&T. I was able to lock onto satellites indoors pretty quickly before. So I rooted my phone with SuperOneClick last night, and everything was good. No problems. However, I was having trouble replacing my recovery file with a modified recovery file. So after some research, I came across Odin on XDA Developers(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1092021&page=8), that was supposed to do exactly what I wanted: Flash me to a stock ROM with root and modified recovery. It was a successful flash, except for one little problem. Any application that used the GPS hardware would fail to initialize. So "luckily" for me, the thread I flashed to root+modified recovery also had a 100% stock ROM to flash my hardware with, so I did that. However, I had the same issue still of not being able to run GPS dependent programs. So I did a manufacturer's reset, and now every application will initialize and run, however I can't LOCK into satellites now! I've tried using GPS status to clear and download AGPS data with no luck. I've tried several different supl servers, including google and nokia, no luck.

I know this is my fault, but can somebody help me out of this mess? The only sort of location that works on my phone is mobile/wifi location.

Thanks in advance for any help I get.

Edit: It appears that even though I flashed a 100% stock rom to my device, there are GPS locking issues with the rom. Damn..

Comment: Go to the dialer and dial `*#*#1472365#*#*`.  Does it bring you to a menu called LbsTestMode? If so, I might be able to help.

Comment: No, but `*#*#3214789650#*#*` brings me to LbsTestMode

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I fixed it!!! I appreciate ANY time you spent researching this for me. I will tell you exactly how I fixed it, so this can help other people with the same problem. I flashed back to the stock+root+modified recovery rom, and then I did a manufacturer's reset of my phone and now everything works flawlessly!

Comment: Great, glad to hear @Apple. I would have suggested something along those lines as well if I were more familiar with your device. You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the flashing wiped out all the info your phone had about local satellites -- the good stuff it retrieves itself, not the aGPS crap :P. If that's the case then hopefully this will help; this a process I've used on my Samsung Vibrant.

1. Ensure GPS is *disabled*
2. Go to LbsTestMode
3. Hit **Delete GPS Data**
4. Go into **Application Settings**
5. Change **Start Mode** to *Cold start*
6. Back out to the home screen, then reboot your phone
7. Enable GPS
8. Go to LbsTestMode
9. Hit **Get Position Test**.  Let this run to completion (normally a good 15 minutes or so) — the lat/long info will get filled in and you'll see `[*]` next to several of the satellites it finds, the more the better.  This will work best if you go outside and walk around.
10. Back out and go into **Application Settings** again.
11. Change **Start Mode** back to *Hot start*.
12. Reboot and, hopefully, enjoy your functional GPS.