# GPS Doesn't Work

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, gps, cyanogenmod

I have SGH-M919 (SGS4 T-Mobile variant). First, it had stock ROM, stock firmware, and it was SIM locked to T-Mobile, so I unlocked it with [SRS server service](http://sam.123unlock.nl/) (I live outside the US, so labs in my area didn't have the tools to unlock it, since it's only a US variant. Also, other methods of unlocking did not work for me, unfortunately).

In the unlocking process I had to flash custom modem file with Odin (it was required for SRS to work). After the successful unlock, I flashed CWM and CM11, rooted the device with [Kingo ROOT](http://www.kingoapp.com/) and everything worked fine except the GPS. It didn't work: no GPS satellites were found.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

I have already tried:

- Reverting to stock firmware (by flash. Kies doesn't work). No only that it didn't fix it, the WiFi broke and couldn't be turned on. I has to recover everything with a recovery file I have made with CWM.
- Installing [stock ROM](http://vip.stockroms.net:81/user/GalaxyS4/SGH-M919/rooted/KitKat/Fenny-UVUFNB4-STOCK-ROOTEDv1.2.zip?token=922379438) via the recovery. The GPS worked(ish), but was very slow. I then restored my CM setup with nandroid restore (again, via the recovery), and the GPS didn't work again.
- While using the stock ROM, I tried to get to LbsTestMode in order to fix the GPS, as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13596/cant-lock-onto-gps-flash-root-possibly-related?rq=1), but I couldn't reach it - it just doesn't exist in Android 4.4.2 apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the helpful [assistance](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=53806067) from couple of people from XDA Developers forum I was able to fix the GPS.

I have found a modem file that was supposed to fix it in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2544612), and did everything by the instructions there.

All I had to do is download a `.zip` file that contains two modem files (MK2 modem) in it, and flash them in order with Odin. 
After that I checked the GPS with [GPS status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) app and it locked onto a satellite blazing fast.

I noticed couple of hours later that suddenly the cellular signal was really weak in area that should have full coverage. So I flashed [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2678774) modem (BN4) and it fixed it (and the GPS also fine).